# Run code on custom artisan command after handle()

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a project running an old version of Laravel (5.6). There's a lot of custom artisan commands in this project. Some of those commands should create a summary on the end of the execution. My first idea was to create a parent class, and all the commands extend from this class, something like:

```
<?php

abstract class ParentCommand extends Command
{

  abstract protected function doYourStuff();
  abstract protected function prepareSummaryData();

  final public function handle()
  {
     $this->doYourStuff();
     $this->createSummary($this->prepareSummaryData());
  }

  final protected function createSummary($data)
  {
     // Summary stuff in here...
  }

}
```

But the problem is that Laravel does DI in the handle method, so the handle method in child classes could have a different signature, which is not allowed.. :(

Any idea of how to run something after the handle() method is executed?

Comment: May be you can call each child command from the parent with the method $this->call. For some children you do the stuff to prepare the summary. Once all children command have been executed you do createSummary.

Comment: @Shaolin They don't run at the same time.. I could change the signature of the command and the parent class and use a parameter do define which one I want to run.. the parent work like a "dispatcher", the problem with this approach is that I would have to change the command in many cronjobs where they are schedulled :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a trait ?

```
trait Summary
{
    protected function createSummary($data)
    {
        // Summary stuff in here...
    }
}

class SomeCommand extends Command
{
    use Summary;
    
    public function handle()
    {
        //do stuff
        //prepare data to summarize
        $this->createSummary($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. That definively works. I still have to call the createSummary() on the end of each handle(), it would be nicer if I didn't need to, but it's perfectly ok! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: In your initial question you were about to edit all children to extend the parent and force them to write 2 new methodes. In my solution you don't have to write so much code, it is just 1 line to add to the children. Also if my solution fits your need then don't forget to tick it ;)